# Building Pybind11 - Test Case will not Run?

Tags: python, c++, installation, build, pybind11

I am currently trying to set up Pybind on my Mac. I am following these instructions: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html.

I have cloned the pybind repo on my computer, created the build directory within that repo, and have ran the test cases (make check -j 4).

Here is my directory layout:

```
Home/
    ---example.cpp
    ---pybind11/
```

I have an example.cpp file that I've written:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int add (int i, int j) {
        return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
        m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

        m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
example.cpp
```

I compile it with the following command and flags (source: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-manually):

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

I get the following error:

```
example.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'pybind11/pybind11.h' file not found
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

When I move my file into the pybind11 repo, I can compile successfully, but executing gives me the following error:

```
zsh: exec format error: ./example.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Follow up: I think Seth got me closer to making it work (thanks a bunch), but I'm still having this issue:

```
    c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix` -I pybind11/include/ 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: No module named pybind11.__main__; 'pybind11' is a package and cannot be directly executed
In file included from example.cpp:1:
In file included from pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:44:
In file included from pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13:
In file included from pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:13:
In file included from pybind11/include/pybind11/pytypes.h:12:
pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:122:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include <Python.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Tried following this guys advice on github but I get the same error: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1728#issuecomment-616619910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file <pybind11/pybind11.h> is not on your include path.  You can install it into your machines default include path, or add -I path_to_directory_containing_pybind11 to your compile command.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. I am not sure how to update my include path... is that not the same thing as my PATH variable?

Comment: see last flag to your compile line:
`c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup \`python3 -m pybind11 --includes\` example.cpp -o example \`python3-config --extension-suffix\` -I /Users/Seth/Developer/pybind11_git_install/`

Comment: Would this update my machines default include path?

Comment: I got the path wrong in my previous comment, it would be `<path>/pybind11_git_install/include`


No, that would just add it to that compile line (not changing the state of your machine).


 My suggestion wasn't to change/update the default include path, the suggestion was to install pybind11 on the current default path (potentially to /usr/local/).  Pybind11 comes with documentation on integrating it into your project. https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/docs/compiling.rst

Comment: Not quite. :/ I get a new error: `fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup `PYTHONPATH=./pybind11 python -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix

Using a makefile works too.